# structure to files and back again

Tags: c++, file, input, line, output

I have a program that puts some strings and integers in  a structure.
now I want to make it so if the program is opened it gets all information from the file and if the program is closed I want to save all info to the same file so I can find it the next time.

What is the best way to do that with one file to put it all in or a seperate file per each variable?

If I have figured that out I need to know how to find a specific line and than read the info from there. (like the name of line 59 goes to the 59th place in a structure array.),
then I have to overwrite certain info like the amount of games played and how many of them are won, lost or tied. (it is a little game.)

Here is the structure:

```
struct Recgame{
    char name[20];
    char surname[20];
    int games;        //needs to be overwritable in file
    int won;          //needs to be overwritable in file
    int same;         //needs to be overwritable in file
    int lost;         //needs to be overwritable in file
    int place;        //needs to be overwritable in file
            int money;        //needs to be overwritable in file
} info[100];
```

Comment: You may want to look up "database", possibly SQLite.

Comment: Since your structure is a POD you might get away with it by just binary-writing your structure to the file with fwrite (if you're not planning to modify it via text files), that might save you some space.

Comment: the files are only written by the program not by me

Comment: This is called "serialisation". You may now perform lots of research on the topic.

Comment: in which format the program writes? binary or text?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The C++ way to do this, is writing an stream-inserter and a stream-extractor for the struct Recgame.
The prototypes are:

```
std::ostream& operator<<( std::ostream& out, const Recgame& recgame );
std::istream& operator>>( std::istream& in, Recgame& recgame );
```

After this, You can easy write the infos to a file

```
ofstream file("afile.txt");
for( int i=0; i<n; ++i ) // n should be the number of the objects
    file << info[i];
```

the implementation of the writing could be:

```
std::ostream& operator<<( std::ostream& out, const Recgame& recgame )
{
    // make sure, that the char-arrays contain a closing char(0) -> ends
    out << recgame.name << "\n";
    out << recgame.surname << "\n";
    out << recgame.games << " " << recgame.won << " " << recgame.same << " " << 
      recgame.lost << " " << recgame.place << " " << recgame.money << "\n";
    return out;
}
```

the implementation of the reading extractor

```
std::istream& operator>>( std::istream& in, Recgame& recgame )
{
    in >> std::skipws;  // skip leading spaces
    in.getline( recgame.name, 20 ).ignore( std::numeric_limits< std::streamsize >::max(), '\n' ); // requires #include <limits>
    in.getline( recgame.surname, 20 ).ignore( std::numeric_limits< std::streamsize >::max(), '\n' );
    in >> recgame.games >> recgame.won >> recgame.same >> 
        recgame.lost >> recgame.place >> recgame.money;
    return in;
}
```

read it from file:

```
ifstream file("afile.txt");
int n = 0; // number of read objects
for( ; n < N && file >> info[n]; ++n ) // -> const int N = 100;
    ;
if( file.eof() )
    cout << "Ok - read until end of file\n";
cout << "read " << n << " objects" << endl;
```

Comment: thanks man it worked. can i put the closing char behind it in the out << statement like this: out << name <<" /0 /n";

Comment: no! the char(0) will NOT be written to the file. The char(0) is the delimiter, to mark the end of the text in memory. Better: use std::string

Comment: so i can do something like copying to a variable and ad "/0" and copy that to the file

Comment: the question is: where the content of Recgame.name and Recgame.surname is from? If You read it from std::cin - like cin.getline( recgame.name, 20 ) - all is Ok, because getline appends a char(0) at the end of the text. Most string-functions do this in the same way. If You use std::string (my recommendation) You don't have such problems.

Comment: I use just normal getline so there is a problem. I might make it so it gets read first and then I replace the /0 with a space

Comment: You shouldn't do this 'replace the /0 with a space'. Use std::string and append a space instead, if necessary.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `fwrite` function in C to write the structure in a binary file, and `fread` to read it back again.

If you want to use C++ style file I/O, then you need to overload `<<` and `>>` operator.

Comment: Sorry, what do you mean by certain line? If you want to access a specific position in the file, you can do that by using `fseek` function. Search Google for `random access binary file in C/C++' for more info.

Comment: u want to read certain line from the file? like only name of 10th entry?

Comment: yes hasan and i want to get all variables that are from that line